# Qt Creator on Windows XP: The procedure entry point strlen could not be located in the dynamic link library msvcrt.dll

Tags: windows, windows-xp, qt-creator

I installed Qt Creator on a Windows XP VM, but it gives me this error message several times:

[image]

I get this message box several times, then Qt Creator starts, but it behaves weird - some widgets don't repaint, and become black boxes:

[image]

Also Qt Creator crashes after I closing, and the crash happens in opengl32sw.dll.

Does this mean that Qt Creator **no longer supports Windows XP**? I assume they no longer test it against Windows XP or they wouldn't have shipped a version with such an obvious error.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out [Qt Creator really has dropped support for XP](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-December/014563.html), because of ANGLE OpenGL:

> As Kenneth reminds us[1](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2013-December/014563.html), Microsoft is ending the security updates for
>   Windows XP in April 2014. That's about when we plan to release Qt 5.3.
>   Actually ANGLE (one of the OpenGL backends we have for Windows) doesn't support Windows XP already now, which is why e.g. Qt Creator 3.0 will not support it either in 5.2.

I ended up downloading an older version of Qt SDK from here - https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.6/, since I don't mind using Qt4. But if the quoted text above is correct, Qt 5.1, should come with Qt Creator that still supports XP as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using the QtCreator-3.5.1 based on Qt-5.5.1 in Windows XP. Just removing the opengl32sw.dll works for me.